# Getting json data from realtime database

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase with unity c#
I stored a JSON object (hero) then when i try to retrieve the object it returns the JSON value in a different order than it was before I don't know if this is the cause of the error or no but when I try to parse it back to the object never works 
why does this happen

````
       public class hero1 : ScriptableObject
{
    public string heroname;
    public string treasure;
    public string[] jewel;
    public float hp;
    public float dps;
    public float def;
    public float spd;
    public float skillvalue;
    public string skilltype;
    public string passivetype;
    public int level;
    public int rank;
    public string type;
    public int starlevel;
    public float totalstats;

}```

this is the hero object that is saved
````

````
  heroes.stringo[x] = heroes1.stringo[x];
  storer2 = (heroes1.stringo[x]);   
          reference.Child("users").Child(server.stringo[0].ToString()).Child("heroes").Child(herohchildnames[x].ToString()).SetRawJsonValueAsync(storer2).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>```
````

this is how it is saved

```
  heroes1.stringo[x] =snapshot.Child("heroes").Child(herohchildnames[x].ToString()).GetRawJsonValue();
                    Debug.Log(snapshot.Child("heroes").Child(herohchildnames[x].ToString()).GetRawJsonValue());
```

and this is how its called back

Comment: Don't describe your code please. Instead, edit your question to **include** the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Although I am sure your question makes perfect sense to you. Its lacking suitable information for us. Sometimes you need to remember we are complete strangers, and we cant debug a story. The better you are at explaining your problem, that faster we can give you an answer (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer the question, I was parsing the data into a different object that had the same properties as the original that was sent